# MonoGame minimises when I click on second game window

Tags: c#, monogame, windows-forms, fullscreen

I've problem with my MonoGame project. I have one full-screen game window and one window form with some info (part of the game too). And the problem lies in when I click on the window form, the main window is minimised. So my question is, how to let the game window on full-screen.